# How to detect when capturing a screen using (MediaProjection, VirtualDisplay) if the window or an app has SECURE_FLAG in Android?

Tags: android, screenshot, mediaprojection

I'm trying to capture screenshots in my android app using MediaProjection by creating VirtualDisplay. It's working fine except in some banking or streaming apps where I get a black screen. I know that it's because in those apps SECURE_FLAG is applied.

My question is, How to detect in my app that the app I'm trying to screenshot has SECURE_FLAG?

Comment: If the screenshot is all black or all white, it was a secure app.  If you're looking to work around this-  you can't, and if you find a way Google will block it as soon as it finds out.  This feature is to protect passwords and personal information.

Comment: But is it possible to check before capturing a screenshot so I can show a notification or something that "Screenshot is not possible because of app security"

Comment: I am not sure how to detect what package has the secure content, but you need the permission android.permission.CAPTURE_SECURE_VIDEO_OUTPUT to capture the event.

Comment: I didn't find any solution for this but I just check if the screenshot is 92% blank then I determine that the app has a SECURE_FLAG.